# How to properly inject mutable config to the controller?

Tags: 8

Apparently by default `ControllerBase::config()` returns `\Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig` object. How can I instantiate the controller class to make it use `\Drupal\Core\Config\Config` instead (which is mutable)?

I know I can do this inside the controller:

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('loremipsum');
```

However this is not the nicest solution. Besides, is there any reason for using `ImmutableConfig` by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two other ways to inject dependencies into a controller, and a third alternative.

#### 1. Implement [ContainerInjectionInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!DependencyInjection!ContainerInjectionInterface.php/interface/ContainerInjectionInterface/8)

This does technically add a dependency to the container. In a unit test, the container would need to be set with `\Drupal::setContainer()` with a mock object of the config factory and config object.

`

```
  public static function create(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static($container->get('config.factory'));
  }

  public function __construct(\Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
    $config = $this->config_factory->getEditable('loremipsum');
  }
```

`

#### 2. Make the [controller a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

This is recommended by all of the Symfony developers that I have asked, and none have been concerned by any performance impact of making all of Drupal's routes use services.

This is subjective, and there is some [contention about the practice](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94341/is-registering-a-controller-as-a-service-still-frowned-upon-in-d8).

#### 3. Use a Form class that extends ConfigFormBase instead.

But, why would a controller want MutableConfig instead of ImmutableConfig? A Form class extending ConfigFormBase instead. A form is probably the best place to modify configuration values such as a class that extends [ConfigFormBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!ConfigFormBase.php/class/ConfigFormBase/8).

Comment: I'm also not a fan of Controller as a service solution. And yes, I'm also one of the "thin controller" advocates. However in this case I needed something for testing and I was surprised that controllers get `ImmutableConfig` on purpose.